# Find matching pairs of dictionaries in a list using Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

In a given list:

```
unmatched_items_array = [{'c': 45}, {'c': 35}, {'d': 5}, {'a': 3.2}, {'a': 3}]
```

Find all 'key' pairs and print out and if no pairs found for given dictionary print out that dictionary.

What I managed to write so far sort of works but it keeps testing some items of the list even though they were already tested. Not sure how to fix it.

```
for i in range(len(unmatched_items_array)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(unmatched_items_array)):
            #  when keys are the same print matching dictionary pairs
            if unmatched_items_array[i].keys() == unmatched_items_array[j].keys():
                print(unmatched_items_array[i], unmatched_items_array[j])
                break
        #  when no matching pairs print currently processed dictionary
        print(unmatched_items_array[i])
```

Output:

```
{'c': 45} {'c': 35}
{'c': 45}
{'c': 35}
{'d': 5}
{'a': 3.2} {'a': 3}
{'a': 3.2}
{'a': 3}
```

What the output should be:

```
{'c': 45} {'c': 35}
{'d': 5}
{'a': 3.2} {'a': 3}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need that? Is the fact of structuring your data as a list of single-pair dicts something you cannot change?

Comment: Can't really change that. That's the way the data comes in. But can process it to something else. Don't know what data structure would be better. As long as I get the matching pairs in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

unmatched_items_array = [{'d': 5}, {'c': 35}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3.2}, {'c': 45}]

for v, g in groupby(sorted(unmatched_items_array, key=lambda k: tuple(k.keys())), lambda k: tuple(k.keys())):
    print([*g])
```

Prints:

```
[{'a': 3}, {'a': 3.2}]
[{'c': 35}, {'c': 45}]
[{'d': 5}]
```

EDIT: If your items in the list are sorted by keys already, then you can skip the `sorted()` call:

```
for v, g in groupby(unmatched_items_array, lambda k: tuple(k.keys()) ):
    print([*g])
```

Comment: Have to say this looks pretty complicated and I don't quite understand how it works but the output I'm getting is not quite the same as yours. [{'d': 5}]
[{'c': 35}]
[{'a': 3}, {'a': 3.2}]
[{'c': 45}] Didn't recognise 'c'

Comment: I did, and it found one pair. [{'a': 3}, {'a': 3.2}]

Comment: @michal-ko Really? are you supplying `unmatched_items_array = [{'c': 45}, {'c': 35}, {'d': 5}, {'a': 3.2}, {'a': 3}]` to the code? Running with this input I get output as In my answer...two pairs `c`, `a` and one single element `d`

Comment: The order is slightly different as it changes every time I run my program. But that shouldn't matter right? If I am sorting it later on. Currently it looks like [{'d': 5}, {'c': 35}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 3.2}, {'c': 45}] and it only finds 'a' pair and prints out the other ones separately :/ I'm on Python 3.5 if that explains anything

Comment: @michal-ko Ok, I'm on Python 3.6. I updated my answer, try the new version.

Comment: Wow, now it works correctly!! Thank you very much sir! So it works differently in older version of Python it seems

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

unmatched_items_array = [{'c': 45}, {'c': 35}, {'d': 5}, {'a': 3.2}, {'a': 3}]
result = defaultdict(list)

for i in unmatched_items_array:
    key, _ = i.items()[0]
    result[key].append(i)          #Group by key. 

for _, v in result.items():        #print Result. 
    print(v)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 3.2}, {'a': 3}]
[{'c': 45}, {'c': 35}]
[{'d': 5}]
```

Comment: Can you explain the advantage of using `defaultdict` in this case please.

Comment: I guess enumerate is better way to iterate unmatched_items_array

Comment: Using `defaultdict ` you do not need to check if the key is present in the result variable. You can directly assign the value. works similar to `setdefault(key, []).append(value)`

Comment: @frankegoesdown sorry I do not understand the use of `enumerate`

Comment: @Rakesh ```for i, d in enumerate(unmatched_items_array): 
    for k, v in d.items(): 
        result[k].append(d) ```

Comment: But what are you doing the index value `i` ?it remains unused

Comment: @ Rakesh Gives me an error: key, _ = i.items()[0] TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Comment: key, _ = list(i.items())[0]